# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongoose, mongodb-query

I've been trying to get data out of a collection, but it returns me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of null. The Mongo database itself is connected with the cloud and checking from there the collection with that name exists.

```
    var output = [];

mongoose.connect(MongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(client) {
    var cursor = client.collection('updates').find();
    cursor.forEach(function(values) {
        output += values;
    });
});
```

I have planned to later use the output for condition check to see, if there are any similar entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As official docs states, mongoose.connect accepts callback for error handling as last argument.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/connections.html

So to find data, you should pass model name and it's schema to mongoose.model, retreive collection,
and then seek for what you need. For instance:

```
const client = mongoose.model("Client", clientScheme);

client.find({}, function(err, docs){
    mongoose.disconnect();
    
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    
    console.log(docs);
});
```

Take a glance at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html